# Regex - extract up until a match and not including that match

Tags: bash

I'm attempting to capture filenames removing both a file-extension and suffix, e.g.:

```
TEST_EXAMPLE_SUFFIX.file
Output = TEST_EXAMPLE
```

I want to do this on the basis of matching the _SUFFIX part and extracting all characters prior to that (not including _SUFFIX). Ordinarily I would use something like:

```
FILE_EXT=_SUFFIX
/.+?(?=$FILE_EXT)/
```

However when piping that together as part of a for-loop:

```
for t in $(ls *.fastq | sed -e /.+?(?=$READ1_EXT)/)
```

I get the error:

```
command substitution: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't parse `ls` output , You could use bash parameter expansion to
achieve what you need

```
for t in *_SUFFIX.fastq 
do
  echo "${t%_SUFFIX.fastq}" #stips _SUFFIX.fastq part
done
```

---

**References**

- See shell [[ param expansion ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).
- On why [[ not to parse ls output ]](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

---

**Edit:**

For working around repeated occurrences, you could do something like this :

Consider that  you have two files  of interest `Test_R1.file` & `Test_R2.file` and you expect `Test` to appear only once in the results do something like

```
declare -A arry # declaring an associative array
for t in Test_R*.file
do
  arry["${t%_R*.file}"]=1 
  # stips _R(number).file part and makes it a key to arry
  # Remember arry keys are unique.
  # The assignment ie '=1' is not relevant here, you can assign any value
done
# We are all set to print the unique filenames
echo "${!arry[@]}"
# "${!arry[@]}" expands to the list of array indices (keys) for arry
```

Comment: Thanks! Out of interest, how would this problem be tackled if | unit was usually added to the loop line as there are multiple files with the same file name but you only want to iterate over unique instances?

Comment: @AnnaSchumann : First of all, in a single directory, as  you're already aware, you can't have  multiple files with the same file name. Did you meant to look for files in subdirectories?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. Let's say all files come in pairs - and are only different due to a suffix _R1 and _ R2 such as Test_R1.file and Test_R2.file. I only want to grab the "Test" part once - but in a normal loop it will show up twice. Ordinarily I would use Rev, cut and uniq to grab "Test" on the loop line but this is quite inflexible if the suffix changes.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense and helped a lot!

Comment: @AnnaSchumann : We iterate over `array keys` which are indeed the `filenames` without suffix using the `!` in front of `arry`. See the param expansion link in the answer, which gives you the explanation of the same and many more cool features.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `bash` parameter expansion only, assuming persistent format of file names:

```
for file in *_SUFFIX.fastq; do echo "${file%_*}"; done
```

The `for` construct iterate over the `.fastq` files.

**Example:**

```
$ file=TEST_EXAMPLE_SUFFIX.fastq

$ echo "${file%_*}"
TEST_EXAMPLE
```

Comment: If you don't use  `*_SUFFIX.fastq`  in the for-loop you may need `echo "${file%_SUFFIX.fastq}"`

Comment: @sjsam fair enough, i have taken OP's example literally..anyway edited..thanks